Finding the Values of x for Different Numbers of Nash Equilibria in a Bimatrix Game
I am currently studying game theory and I've come across a problem involving a bimatrix game that I'm having trouble with. I would appreciate any help or guidance.
The Problem:
Consider the following bimatrix game:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(1,1) & (1,x) & (3,0) \\
(2,3) & (2,2) & (2,1) \\
(2x,1) & (3,x) & (x^2,4)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $$x \in \mathbb{R}$$.
The task is to find all values of x such that:

The game has no pure Nash equilibrium.
The game has exactly two pure Nash equilibria.
The game has exactly three Nash equilibria.

My Background:
I have a basic understanding of game theory and Nash equilibrium. I understand the concept of a Nash equilibrium in a game and how to find it in a 2x2 matrix game. However, I am not very familiar with finding Nash equilibria in larger games or how changes in the payoff values might affect the number of equilibria.
My Attempts:
I tried to solve the problem by setting up the conditions for a Nash equilibrium and solving for x. However, I am not sure if I am setting up the conditions correctly, especially for the cases where there are multiple equilibria.
For the first part, I tried to find conditions under which none of the cells would be a Nash equilibrium. I set up inequalities for each cell such that the row player would always have a profitable deviation. However, I am not sure if this is the correct approach.
For the second and third parts, I am unsure how to proceed. I understand that a game can have multiple Nash equilibria, but I am not sure how to find conditions under which there would be exactly two or three equilibria.
Questions:

How can I set up the conditions for a Nash equilibrium in this game correctly?
How can I find the values of x that satisfy these conditions?
Is there a systematic way to approach problems like this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I would look at each of the nine outcomes to see when it is a Nash equilibrium.  For example top left $(1,1)$ never is as Player A can switch to $(2,3)$; middle left $(2,3)$ might be a Nash equilibrium when $x<1$, avoiding  Player A switching to $(1,1)$ or $(2x,1)$ and Player B not switching to $(2,2)$ or $(2,1)$.  And so on.

Could you explain a bit more about the reasoning behind the "avoiding switching"?

If you know I am planning to make a choice $z$ and if I know you are planning to make a choice $y$, then I will avoid switching from $z$ if all my other options will give me a worse outcome than $z$ does when you choose $y$, while you will avoid switching from $y$ if all your other options will give you a worse outcome than $y$ does when I choose $z$.  If in this sense we are both going to avoid switching from my choice $z$ and your choice $y$ then together they are a Nash equilibrium.

Is it an assignment?

Suppose you are the "row" player. In general, your strategy can be defined by two parameters: $p_1$ and $p_2$ (you are adopting a mixed strategy), where the former is the probability of adopting option 1 and the latter option 2 (obviously, the probability of adopting option 3 is $1-p_1-p_2$).
You can evaluate how any fixed strategy from the "col" player fares against this $(p_1, p_2)$ strategy. You have the equilibrium for those $(p_1, p_2)$ that make any "col" fixed strategy indifferent.
Say that the "col" player adopts the $(1,0)$ strategy (they always play first option). Their expected payoff is:
$$
E_1 = p_1 + 3 p_2 + (1-p_1-p_2)
$$
For the $(0,1)$ strategy you have:
$$
E_2 = p_1x + 2 p_2 + x(1-p_1-p_2)
$$
Finally, for the $(0,0)$ strategy:
$$
E_3 =  p_2 + 4(1-p_1-p_2)
$$
Now, to make the "col" player indifferent, you set that those three values are the same:
$$
E_1 = E_2
$$
$$
E_1 = E_3
$$
You can solve those for $(p_1, p_2)$ and they will be function of $x$. Since they have to be in [0,1] range and their sum can not be bigger than 1, you will obtain some conditions on $x$ in order to have solutions.
You do the same reversing the perspective on the "row" player playing fixed strategies, while the "col" player plays a $(q_1, q_2)$ strategy such as the row player's fixed strategies have all the same value.
